# Multiple Social SDK's but unique identity

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I am trying to take a backup of my Database and store it server side. The reason for this is that if a user loses his phone or changes his phone from iPhone to Android or the other way round, I want to give user an option to restore from previous backup on my server.

For this first thing first I need a unique id for each user so that I can differentiate between users.

The first thing here is to make user login via:

1) Facebook

2) Google+

3) Twitter

4) Make a custom login (Which is directly stored in my db at server)

Now a logical problem which arises here is that What if the user signs in to my app using Google+ - Backs up data on my server - loses his phone. Installs a new copy of my app on a new phone and logs in with Facebook - I dont recognize his Facebook credentials as previously he had provided me Google+ credentials.

As a solution I think I should provide only one Socal SDK login in my app - how far am I correct or are there any workarounds?

Comment: This is totally a guess, but I believe many apps with multiple login options query user email address and use that to recognise users using other login option at a later time.

Comment: Which is not fool proof?